How to get enum documentation in Swagger
I am working with a Swagger API documentation and want to have my description of the enums in the documentation. I am using a custom filter to extract information from classes and enums, using annotations.
e.g.:
    using System.ComponentModel;
    ...
    [DisplayName("Upload class")]            // Works fine
    public class Upload
    {
        [DisplayName("Primary Key")]          // Works fine
        public int UploadMetaId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "document name")]     // Works fine too
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

But I have problems with my Enums:
[DisplayName("Document types")]    // Illegal, gives error CS0592
// or
[Display(Name = "Document types")]  // Illegal too, gives also CS0592
public enum UploadType
{
    [Display(Name = "Årsopgørelse")] // Works fine
    PartnerAarsopgoerelse = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Ægtefælles årsopgørelse")]
    AegtefaelleAarsopgoerelse = 2
}

The error CS0592 says it's not valid on this declaration type.
So what can I use instead?
UPDATE
I am using the following NuGet packages:

Microsoft.OpenApi (1.6.15)
SwashBucle.AspNetCore(6.6.2)


Enums in C# aren't classes, they're essentially labelled integers

Answer might depend on the package generating the Open API description. Swashbuckle, NSwag etc.

That might help.

DisplayAttribute and DisplayNameAttribute don't work on enum types, they lack AttributeTargets.Enum in their AttributeUsage definition.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute

Thanks to @ralf and the article in his comment, I created a solution with my own IDocumentFilter.
I hope I can save someone for a lot of searches by using the code below.
I program.cs I pick up the XML documentation from the project and pass relevant 'summary' to the IDocumentFilter:
 private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     ...
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
     {
         ...
         Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
         foreach (var filePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xml"))
         {
             c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
             GetXMLDoc(filePath, Dict);          
         }
         c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter>(Dict);               
     });
 }

private static void GetXMLDoc(string path, Dictionary<string,string> Dict)
{
    var _xmlComments = new XmlDocument();
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
    _xmlComments.Load(reader);
    var xpath = $"//member[@name[starts-with(.,'F')] or @name[starts-with(.,'T')]]";
    var nodes = _xmlComments.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var attribute = node.Attributes["name"];
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            string summary = node.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim(' ','\n');
            Dict.Add(attribute.Value, summary);
        }
    }
}

In the filter I pick up the XML documentation from the passed dictionary:
public class SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{

    Dictionary<string, string> EnumDescription = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter(Dictionary<string, string> enumDescription)
    {
        EnumDescription = enumDescription;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // add enum descriptions Schemas section in Swagger
        foreach (var property in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
        {
            var propertyEnums = property.Value.Enum;
            if (propertyEnums is { Count: > 0 })
            {
                property.Value.Description += DescribeEnum(property.Key, false);
            }
        }

        if (swaggerDoc.Paths.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        //add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            foreach (var operation in pathItem.Operations)
            {
                if (operation.Value.Parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var param in operation.Value.Parameters)
                    {
                        if (param.Schema.Reference != null)
                        {
                            param.Description += DescribeEnum(param.Schema.Reference.Id, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Type GetEnumTypeByName(string enumTypeName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumTypeName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                            .Single(x => x.FullName != null && x.Name == enumTypeName);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"SwaggerDoc: Can not find a unique Enum for specified typeName '{enumTypeName}'. Please provide a more unique enum name.");
        }
    }

    private string DescribeEnum(string propertyTypeName, bool inApiList)
    {
        var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(propertyTypeName);

        if (enumType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        if (values == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string result = "<ul>";

        if (inApiList)
        {
            var key = $"T:{enumType.FullName}";
            var summary = EnumDescription.ContainsKey(key) ? EnumDescription[key] : "";
            result = $"<p>{summary}</p><ul>";
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var key = $"F:{enumType.FullName}.{value}";
            var summary = EnumDescription.ContainsKey(key) ? EnumDescription[key] : "";
            string n = EnumUtils.GetDisplayName((System.Enum)value);
            result += $"<li>{(int)value} - {n} : {summary} </li>";
        }
        result += "</ul>";
        return result;
    }

}

